# My Django form data won't save to my database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, mariadb

I'm trying to get a simple form to save to my MariaDB database but I can't get it to save when I use the form. If I use the Django Admin interface, I can make changes to the database however.

**addstudent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Student</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Add a student</h1>

    <form id="studentform" method="post" action="/add-student/index/">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Student" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**views.py***

```
def addstudent(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = studentform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print (form.errors)
    else:
        form = studentform()
    return render(request, 'addstudent/addstudent.html', {'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
class student(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    other_names = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
```

**forms.py**

```
DOY = ('1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987',
       '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995',
       '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003',
       '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011',
       '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015')

class studentform(forms.ModelForm):
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="Last name")
    other_names = forms.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="Other names")
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget = extras.SelectDateWidget(years = DOY ), help_text="Date Of Birth")

    class Meta:
        model = student
        fields = ('last_name', 'other_names', 'date_of_birth',)
```

Any ideas as to why it's not saving to the database?

Comment: What does it do? any errors?

Comment: @Sayse no errors, it will continue on to the index page as it should but when I go to check the database manually it says it is an empty set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action is set to what I assume is the index page also which means its probably not calling that view whatsoever

```
<form id="studentform" method="post" action="/add-student/index/">
```

The action here should point to the url that links to that particular view (preferably using the `url` template tag)

Comment: Ah thanks very much. What a silly error, I don't know how I didn't see that